# additional firmware, when installing debian buster, is not detected

Tags: system-installation, debian-installer

I have installed debian many times before, with little problem.

What I did:

- add a vfat file system after the iso image
- copy `firmware-iwlwifi_20190114-1_all.deb` to this partition.
- boot installer (Bios mode)
- select advanced options
- select expert graphical install
- skip language and keyboard (this is what I remember from before, and don't see that it is relevant, and am getting fed up with doing it)
- load installation components. (this seems new)

  - select load-media
- select load drivers from removable media **This fails**

Error: Detected removable media that is not known driver media. Please make sure that the correct media is inserted. You can still continue if you have an unofficial removable media you want to use.

Unknown removable media. Try to load anyway?

- Yes

Error: There was a problem reading data from the removable media. Please make sure that the right media is present. If you continue to have trouble, your removable media might be bad.

Cannot read removable media, or no drivers found.

- Go to command line, type `mount /dev/sdb3 /media`. This mounts the file-system. But I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked:

- add a vfat file system after the iso image
- copy `firmware-iwlwifi_20190114-1_all.deb` to this partition.
- boot installer (Bios mode)
- select advanced options
- select expert graphical install
- load installation components. (this seems new)

  - select load-media
- **skip load drivers from removable media** (It is not needed. It is added by previous step, but is not needed, and I don't know what it does. The next step is also added by previous step.
- detect network